# Android: Is there a way to change an image without using a Custom Adapter?

Tags: android, image, listview, custom-adapter

My activity extends ListActivity. This is how I set the list to the Adapter:

```
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
     this, R.layout.imgTxtView,
      R.id.items,retrievedTasks));
```

RetrivedTasks is a String of tasks/items stored in shared pref.

I have this List in a Linear Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 

        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is another Linear Layout (imgTxtView) that serves as a row in the List

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/icon"
  android:layout_width="22dp"
  android:layout_height="22dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:src="@drawable/star" />


 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/Itemname"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="17sp" 
 android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

The idea is when you click on just the image the image will change and the background for the TextView items.

All solutions talk about a Custom Adapter.

Now, is there a way to accomplish this WITHOUT using one?

EDIT. A piece of code Im trying atm.

```
ImageView theStar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
    theStar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
            ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
            final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item clicked: "+Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       });
```

EDIT_2. Now full code to both linear layouts uploaded. I hate it when ppl post long lines of code, I was trying to avoid that.

I know its not hard to implement a Custom Adapter, but was curious if someone managed to do this without using one.

Comment: It may be helpful to post the relevant code for the ListView and ImageView, at least.

Comment: Do consider using an ArrayAdapter (CustomAdapter) since I don't think it's hard to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. My understanding is that this a custom listview and you need to use a custom adapter to have access to all properties.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my English, but I hope and serve him this. This is 100% functional !, works for me

```
 package com.exa.Usuario;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.basedatos.BD_Mundial;
import com.app.basedatos.ConnectionDetector;
import com.app.basedatos.responseJson;
import com.exa.citas.DetalleContacto;
import com.exa.citas.R;

public class Contactos extends  Activity implements OnClickListener, OnQueryTextListener {

    public class AtributosContactos {


        String nombre,apellido,correo,telefono; 
        String idContacto,Separador;

    }

    ListView list_contactos;
    SearchView search_contact;

    private CodeLearnAdapter chapterListAdapter;

    BD_Mundial adb = new BD_Mundial(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db;

     String idUsu;

     SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
     SharedPreferences prefs;

    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuario_contactos);
        getActionBar().hide();
        header();



        prefs = getSharedPreferences("Datos_usuario", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        idUsu = prefs.getString("idUsu","");

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        list_contactos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_contactos);
         search_contact = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_contact);
        list_contactos.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        new Async_ranking().execute();
        setupSearchView();

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        if(isInternetPresent){
            SincronizaContactos();
            EliminaContactos();
        }


        list_contactos.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                AtributosContactos ch=chapterListAdapter.getCodeLearnChapter(arg2);
                if(ch.Separador.equals("0")){

                    Intent i=new Intent (getApplicationContext(),DetalleContacto.class);
                    i.putExtra("Nombre", ch.nombre);
                    i.putExtra("Apellido", ch.apellido);
                    i.putExtra("Telefono", ch.telefono);
                    i.putExtra("Correo", ch.correo);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //Log.i("ID:", ch.idContacto);
                }



            }

        });
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);


        search_contact.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        search_contact.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        search_contact.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
        search_contact.setQueryHint("Buscar Contactos");
        search_contact.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {

             new Async_ranking().execute();;
            } else {
                //String contacto=newText.replaceAll("\\s", "");

                //Log.i("", "Entro"+newText);
                chapterListAdapter.filter(newText);
                //list_contactos.setFilterText(newText.toString());
            }
        return true;
    }

    public void header() {

        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        ImageView btn_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        ImageView btn_2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        TextView txtTitulo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);

        btn_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_add);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_2:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddContacto.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_back:
            onBackPressed();
            break;

        }
    }

    private class Async_ranking extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SoapObject> {

        @Override
        protected SoapObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            chapterListAdapter = new CodeLearnAdapter();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject result) {

            list_contactos.setAdapter(chapterListAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }

    }

public class CodeLearnAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<AtributosContactos> codeLeanChapterList = getDataForListView();
    private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
      ArrayList<String> mItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return codeLeanChapterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AtributosContactos getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return codeLeanChapterList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }




    @Override
        public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {





        if (arg1 == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Contactos.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contacto, arg2, false);
        }

        TextView txt_nombre = (TextView) arg1 .findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre);

        TextView txt_num = (TextView) arg1 .findViewById(R.id.txt_num);
        TextView txt_correo= (TextView) arg1 .findViewById(R.id.txt_correo);



        final AtributosContactos ch = codeLeanChapterList.get(arg0);
        if(ch.Separador.equals("1")){
            txt_num.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txt_correo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eaeaea"));
            arg1.setSelected(false);
            arg1.setEnabled(false);
            //arg1.setFocusable(false);
        }else {
            txt_num.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt_correo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
            arg1.setSelected(true);
            arg1.setEnabled(true);
            //arg1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        }
         txt_nombre.setText(ch.nombre+" "+ch.apellido);
        txt_num.setText(ch.telefono);
        txt_correo.setText(ch.correo);
        // Log.i("Letra1: " +arg0,"Valor separador   "+ch.Separador);

        return arg1;
    }



    /**
     * 
     * @param contacto
     * 
     * Filtra la lista de contactos  aqui se hace toda la búsqueda... Soy una Pipi! :3 ajaja
     */
    public void filter(String contacto) {

            contacto = contacto.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            contacto=    (contacto );

            codeLeanChapterList.clear();

            if (contacto.length() == 0) {
                codeLeanChapterList = getDataForListView();
            } else {
                for (AtributosContactos wp : getDataForListView()) {

                    String nombreContacto=wp.nombre+" "+wp.apellido;
                    //Busca por nombre y apellido
                    if (nombreContacto.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains( contacto)  ) {
                        codeLeanChapterList.add(wp);
                    }else/**Busca por correo */
                        if (wp.correo.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains( contacto)  ) {
                        codeLeanChapterList.add(wp);
                    }else /**Busca por telefono */
                        if (wp.telefono.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains( contacto)  ) {
                        codeLeanChapterList.add(wp);
                    }
                }
                list_contactos.setAdapter(chapterListAdapter);
            }

        }

        public AtributosContactos getCodeLearnChapter(int position) {
            return codeLeanChapterList.get(position);
        }

}



@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public List<AtributosContactos> getDataForListView() {
    final List<AtributosContactos> codeLeanChaptersList = new ArrayList<AtributosContactos>();


        SQLiteDatabase db = adb.openDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT idContacto,  nombre,apellido,correo,telefono FROM tblContacto"
                + " where borrado=0   order by  nombre COLLATE BINARY COLLATE NOCASE", null);
        ArrayList<String> Header = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                AtributosContactos chapter = new AtributosContactos();
                AtributosContactos ch = new AtributosContactos();

                String letra = mCursor.getString(1).substring(0, 1);

                String c = letra.toUpperCase();
                if (Header.size() > 0) {
                    int cont = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < Header.size(); i++) {
                        if (Header.get(i).equals(c)) {
                            cont++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (cont == 0) {
                        char res= c.charAt(0);




                        if ((res >= 'a' && res <= 'z') || (res >= 'A' && res <= 'Z')) {
                            Header.add(c);
                                ch.idContacto = " ";
                                ch.nombre = c;
                                ch.apellido = " ";
                                ch.correo = " ";
                                ch.telefono = " ";
                                ch.Separador = "1";

                                codeLeanChaptersList.add(ch);
                                chapter.idContacto = mCursor.getString(0);
                                chapter.nombre = mCursor.getString(1);
                                chapter.apellido = mCursor.getString(2);
                                chapter.correo = mCursor.getString(3);
                                chapter.telefono = mCursor.getString(4);
                                chapter.Separador = "0";
                                codeLeanChaptersList.add(chapter);
                            } else   {
                                // Agregamos el contacto
                                chapter.idContacto = mCursor.getString(0);
                                chapter.nombre = mCursor.getString(1);
                                chapter.apellido = mCursor.getString(2);
                                chapter.correo = mCursor.getString(3);
                                chapter.telefono = mCursor.getString(4);
                                chapter.Separador = "0";
                                codeLeanChaptersList.add(chapter);
                            }



                    } else {
                        // Agregamos el contacto
                        chapter.idContacto = mCursor.getString(0);
                        chapter.nombre = mCursor.getString(1);
                        chapter.apellido = mCursor.getString(2);
                        chapter.correo = mCursor.getString(3);
                        chapter.telefono = mCursor.getString(4);
                        chapter.Separador = "0";

                        codeLeanChaptersList.add(chapter);
                    }

                } else {

                    char res= c.charAt(0);




                    if ((res >= 'a' && res <= 'z') || (res >= 'A' && res <= 'Z')) {
                        Header.add(c);
                            ch.idContacto = " ";
                            ch.nombre = c;
                            ch.apellido = " ";
                            ch.correo = " ";
                            ch.telefono = " ";
                            ch.Separador = "1";

                            codeLeanChaptersList.add(ch);
                            chapter.idContacto = mCursor.getString(0);
                            chapter.nombre = mCursor.getString(1);
                            chapter.apellido = mCursor.getString(2);
                            chapter.correo = mCursor.getString(3);
                            chapter.telefono = mCursor.getString(4);
                            chapter.Separador = "0";
                            codeLeanChaptersList.add(chapter);
                        } else   {
                            // Agregamos el contacto
                            chapter.idContacto = mCursor.getString(0);
                            chapter.nombre = mCursor.getString(1);
                            chapter.apellido = mCursor.getString(2);
                            chapter.correo = mCursor.getString(3);
                            chapter.telefono = mCursor.getString(4);
                            chapter.Separador = "0";
                            codeLeanChaptersList.add(chapter);
                        }

                }

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());

        }

        db.close();
        adb.close();




    return codeLeanChaptersList;

}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

item_contacto.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_nombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Juan Perez"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_correo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="gortiz@exagononononono.net"
            android:textColor="@color/negro" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="01234567890"
            android:textColor="@color/negro" />

    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.exa.Usuario.Contactos" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_contact"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#EAEAEA" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_contactos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

hope and be your help

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to answer, but CodeLearnAdapter is a Custom Adapter and I don't want to use one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required to use Adapters with ListView but I am concerned you may have UI overlapping issues between ListView, TextView and ImageView. Let's assume you don't.

There are listeners for `ImageView`. You need setOnClickListener in your case. A crude example:

```
ImageView theStar = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon);

theStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(...
    TextView itemText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.items);
    itemText.setBackground(R.Color...
  }
});
```

I hope this gives you an idea. Keep us posted.

Comment: If you have overlapping UI issues, then we'll have to look at your layouts closely.

Comment: Thanks. No overlapping issues. The app works just fine as it is. Yea, I tried setting a setOnClickListener but I need to change just one image, the one that is being clicked, otherwise it will change all of them.

Comment: I added a piece of code to my answer. Im trying it atm just to see if I can get the position of the item clicked.

Comment: ed-ta, I noticed you want to get the parent view (ListView). I am not sure you can do that since I have never tried it. However my sample code gets the UI element (Textview in my case) in the current view. And you can do the same with other UI in the same row.

Comment: If your ImageView is in a Layout, which is common, you may need getParent().getParent() to get the ListView.

Comment: ed-ta, In my code sample, I set the text background on a particular row, not the entire imageview on a ListView. I am now assuming that your image is contained in the ListView.